# Angular 2 - scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' does not work on every component

Tags: angular, apexcharts

My problem is while clicking and changing routes, the screen starts from the bottom.Then,
I've added it in my app.module.ts .

**RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, {
scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
})**

and i am using Apexcharts.js in some of my components.Those who dont have charts work smoothly, others dont...

Tried lots of things but the result is same.